# Implicit Euler looks different from Runge-Kutta implicit Euler

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods, eulers-method

In theory Implicit (Backward) Euler should be a Runge-Kutta method with tableu given below, however I find that the standard Backward Euler formula and the Runge-Kutta one differ.
$$
{\begin{array}{c|c}1&1\\\hline &1\\\end{array}}
$$
Here are the two methods:

- Standard Implicit Euler $y_{n+1} = y_n + h f(t_{n+1}, y_{n+1})$ where $t_{n+1} = t_n + h$.
- Runge-Kutta with tableu above gives
  $$
  \begin{align}
      k_1 &= f(t_0 + h, y_0 + hk_1) \\
      y_1 &= y_0 + hk_1
  \end{align}
  $$

#### Runge Kutta formulas

I have used the formulas in Geometric Numerical Integration by Hairer
$$
\begin{align}
    k_i &= f\left(t_0 + c_i h, y_0 + h\sum_{i=1}^s a_{ij} k_j\right) \\
    y_1 &= y_0 + h\sum_{i=1}^s b_i k_i
\end{align}
$$
and Implicit Euler has $c_1 = 1$, $a_{11} = 1$ and $b_1 = 1$.

Comment: Not sure how you found they differ because [they are the same](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_Euler_method).

Comment: Eliminate $k_1$ and you get again $y_1=y_0+hf(t_0+h,y_1)$.